# При использовании quartz для массовых рассылок выходит ошибка в asp net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp, quartz

Я пытаюсь реализовать в Asp net, массовую рассылку через quartz как здесь https://m.habr.com/ru/post/486678/,
При обращении к контекстному классу выходит ошибка:
Message "Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.\r\nObject name: 'MemoryContext'." string[image: вот в этом моменте вылетает в кэтч]

Comment: А чего вы EmailSender получаете из scope, а контекст бд используете уже созданный? Создавайте контекст также как EmailSender.

Comment: Я использовал с хабра исходник он работает по этой схеме, но как только начинаю обращаться к бд перестает работать

Comment: Перечитайте мой комментарий. Там уже есть для вас рекомендация.

Comment: Сработало ! спасибо Вам огромное)))